# String array initialization as constructor parameter

Tags: java, arrays, string, constructor

In Java, it is completely legal to initialize a String array in the following way:

```
String[] s = {"FOO", "BAR"};
```

However, when trying to instantiate a class that takes a String array as a parameter, the following piece of code is NOT allowed:

```
Test t = new Test({"test"});
```

But this works again:

```
Test t = new Test(new String[] {"test"});
```

Can someone explain why this is?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
String[] s = {"FOO", "BAR"};
```

this is allowed at declaration time only

You can't

```
String[] s;
s={"FOO", "BAR"};
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `Type[] x = { ... }` is an **initialization** syntax for arrays. The `{ ... }` is interpreted in a specific way only in that specific context.

Answer (score 3):

For you want a simple way to pass a String array, I suggest you use varargs

```
class Test {
   public Test(String...args);
}

// same as new Test(new String[] { "test", "one" })
Test t = new Test("test", "one");
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't really the question and you are also assuming that we can modify the constructor.

Comment: @Herminator Usually you can, but not always.  Next time you can you will know what you can do.