# Initializing a new object of a class that contains an array

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I'm new at java, not doing well, need some help. I have a class called "RestaurantObject" and I am trying to create an object from that class in my main. I'm having a problem because one of the variables in that object is an array. I'm just really not sure what to put there.

Here is my main:

```
public class MyRestaurantObject {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

     RestaurantObject mcDonalds = new RestaurantObject("McDonalds", "McDonalds Menu", **WHAT GOES HERE?**);
```

Here is the code from my class "RestaurantObjects"

```
public class RestaurantObject {

private static final Object[] String = null;
private String restaurantName;
private String menu;
private String [] employees;


public RestaurantObject(String name, String menu, String [] employees){
setRestaurantName(name);
setMenu(menu);
setEmployees(employees);
}


//restaurantName
public String getRestaurantName(){
return restaurantName;
}

private void setRestaurantName(String name){
restaurantName = name;
}

//menu
public String getMenu(){
return menu;
}

private void setMenu(String menu){
this.menu = menu;
}

//employees
public String[] getEmployees(){
return employees;

}

private void setEmployees(String [] employees){
this.employees = employees;
}

}
```

I know I'm not doing this right. Please help!

Thank you!

Also, please correct me if any of my terminology is wrong.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but it should help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4436458/422353

Answer (score 2):

Just pass a new string array in the 3rd argument.

```
RestaurantObject mcDonalds = new RestaurantObject("McDonalds", "McDonalds Menu", new String[] {"Value1", "Value2"});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you haven't learned Java varargs yet, but this is a perfect case where to use them.  Then you could go

```
public RestaurantObject(String name, String menu, String...employees) {
   setRestaurantName(name);
   setMenu(menu);
   setEmployees(employees);
}
```

and later,

```
RestaurantObject mcDonalds = new RestaurantObject(
        "McDonalds", "McDonalds Menu", "John Doe", "Jane Doe");
```

If you can't use or haven't learned varargs yet, @fvu version 2 is my preference.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two options:

1  Create the array before your create your `RestaurantObject` (The class should really just be called `Restaurant`

```
String[] emplArr = new String[]{ "Bob", "Alice", "Fred"};
RestaurantObject mcDonalds;
mcDonalds = new RestaurantObject("McDonalds", "McDonalds Menu", emplArr);
```

2  Intialize an array with a static intializer in the constructor call for `RestaurantObject`

```
RestaurantObject mcDonalds;
mcDonalds = new RestaurantObject("McDonalds", "McDonalds Menu", new String[]{ "Bob", "Alice", "Fred"});
```

Comment: My teacher keeps calling them "objects" and he was specific about what this class should be called. It's bothering me as well. How can i initialize the array in the constructor call? Thank you very much.

Comment: Well there is a difference between a `Class` and an `Object`. You can think of a `Class` as a blueprint for an `Object`, it documents all the properties that `Objects` of that class possess. An `Object` on the other hand is a specific instance of a `Class`. So in your class `mcDonalds` is the instance of your `Restaurant` class that is specific to the McDonald's restaurant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
RestaurantObject mcDonalds = new RestaurantObject(
    "McDonalds", "McDonalds Menu", new String[] {"John Doe", "Jane Doe"});
```

or

```
String[] employees = new String[] {"John Doe", "Jane Doe"};
RestaurantObject mcDonalds = new RestaurantObject(
    "McDonalds", "McDonalds Menu", employees);
```

or

```
String[] employees = new String[2];
employees[0] = "John Doe";
employees[1] = "Jane Doe";
RestaurantObject mcDonalds = new RestaurantObject(
    "McDonalds", "McDonalds Menu", employees);
```

A note regarding the latter: when you create an array like this, you have to know its size, which can be quite annoying sometimes.  That's why many people will prefer to use `ArrayList`s which behaves more or less like an elastic array, ie it autoexpands when n item is added.