# Populating already declared multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there any way to populate the rows of an already declared multidimensional array without a for loop? can I now add in a row of information at one time?

ex: I declare an array 3 x 3

```
int[][] newArray = new int[3][3];
```

I've tried to now do something like this

```
newArray[1] = {143, 124, 453};
```

but I get tons of errors, and changing the brackets to other things doesn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String array initialization as constructor parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436458/string-array-initialization-as-constructor-parameter)

Comment: Try `newArray[1] = new int [] {143, 124, 453};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[][] newArray = new int[3][3];

newArray [0]=new int[]{10,13,14};
newArray [1]=new int[]{10,13,14};
newArray [2]=new int[]{10,13,14};
```

or

```
newArray=new int[][] {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set all the fields in a row at once, you either need to set them up during construction using

```
int[][] newArray = { {1,2,3}, {2,3,4}, {3,4,5} }
```

or if you want to do this at a later time, you can construct a new one dimensional array and assign that to a row, such as

```
int[] row = {2,3,4};
newArray[1] = row;
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't know I had to declare it as a new array first, this makes a lot more sense now. thanks